# Attribute a range to a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a combobox on my website with the months from January to December and on my database I have a normal date "dd-mm-yyyy".

I wish to have a variable that stores the month from the combobox and then automatically assigns the correct days to it, for instance January would be  `BETWEEN '01-01-2020' AND '31-01-2020'`

This is my code

```
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(10) = #month#
SELECT @month   = CASE WHEN 1 THEN BO.finaldate BETWEEN '01-01-2020' AND '31-01-2020'
WHEN 2 THEN BO.finaldate BETWEEN '01-02-2020' AND '28-02-2020'
WHEN 3 THEN BO.finaldate BETWEEN '01-03-2020' AND '31-03-2020'
WHEN 4 THEN BO.finaldate BETWEEN '01-04-2020' AND '30-04-2020'
WHEN 5 THEN BO.finaldate BETWEEN '01-10-2020' AND '31-10-2020'
WHEN 6 THEN BO.finaldate BETWEEN '01-06-2020' AND '30-06-2020'
WHEN 7 THEN BO.finaldate BETWEEN '01-07-2020' AND '31-07-2020'
WHEN 8 THEN BO.finaldate BETWEEN '01-08-2020' AND '31-08-2020'
WHEN 9 THEN BO.finaldate BETWEEN '01-09-2020' AND '30-09-2020'
WHEN 10 THEN BO.finaldate BETWEEN '01-10-2020' AND '31-10-2020'
WHEN 11 THEN BO.finaldate BETWEEN '01-11-2020' AND '30-11-2020'
ELSE BO.finaldate BETWEEN '01-12-2020' AND '31-12-2020'
END
SELECT id, name, finaldate
FROM bo
WHERE finaldate = @month
```

But it is giving me this error

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.

It would be interesting if I could have a variable that would change the year, but this isn't the most important since I can just change it manually on the code

Comment: A `CASE` **expression** returns a scalar value, not a boolean result. `BO.finaldate BETWEEN '01-11-2020' AND '30-11-2020'` is not a scalar value, and you try to assign that to a `varchar`. `BO.finaldate` doesn't even have any context in that `CASE` expression;` what are you *really* trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your query to use DATEPART() instead of coding the month function yourself.

```
SELECT id, name, finaldate
FROM bo
WHERE DATEPART(month, finaldate) = [INSERT YOUR MONTH VARIABLE]
```

Comment: Whilst this will work there are a couple of things to note. 1) you won't be able to use any indexes that might be available on the `finaldate` field as the function call makes it non-sargable. 2) This will include values from previous (and future) years, not just 2020!

Comment: To prevent this from giving me previous and future years I added another condition with another variable: `DATEPART(year, BO.finaldate) = @year`

Answer (score 0):

You can't build a dynamic `WHERE` clause like that.

Instead you need to work out the start and end date of the period you are searching for.

```sql
DECLARE @month_string VARCHAR(10) = 'January';
DECLARE @month int = CASE @month_string
                       WHEN 'January'   THEN  1
                       WHEN 'February'  THEN  2
                       WHEN 'March'     THEN  3
                       WHEN 'April'     THEN  4
                       WHEN 'May'       THEN  5
                       WHEN 'June'      THEN  6
                       WHEN 'July'      THEN  7
                       WHEN 'August'    THEN  8
                       WHEN 'September' THEN  9
                       WHEN 'October'   THEN 10
                       WHEN 'November'  THEN 11
                       WHEN 'December'  THEN 12
                       ELSE NULL
                     END
;

DECLARE @start_of_month date = DateFromParts(2020, @month, 1);
DECLARE @end_of_month   date = EOMonth(@start_of_month);

SELECT id
     , name
     , finaldate
FROM   bo
WHERE  finaldate >= @start_of_month
AND    finaldate <= @end_of_month
;
```

Now, you also need to be extra careful depending on the data type of `finaldate`. If this a date that contains a time portion (e.g. `datetime`) then your query will end up missing some data (the times after midnight on the last day of the month).

To cater for this you should change the end of month comparison to instead be less-than the first day of the next month.

This can be achieved like this:

```sql
DECLARE @start_of_month      date = DateFromParts(2020, @month, 1);
DECLARE @start_of_next_month date = DateAdd(mm, 1, @start_of_month);

...
WHERE  finaldate >= @start_of_month
AND    finaldate <  @start_of_next_month
;
```

Comment: I've hard-coded 2020 in as the year, which obviously isn't ideal either (as it won't work for 2021!). You will need to clarify what your desired behaviour is in order to correct this. For instance, if you want it to always be the "current year" then `Year(GetUtcDate())` can just replace the 2020 literal.

Comment: This is great, but in my case, the variable is varchar, so it doesn't work with DateFromParts... I've tried `CASE @month WHEN 'January' THEN '1' END` before declaring the start and end of month.

Comment: @pauLo_0liveira then you need to convert from a string to an integer. I've updated my answer to include an approach to this.